# get most represented day and hour from an array of carbon objects

Tags: php, php-carbon

I have an array of carbon objects and i want the day and hour that is most times represented in that array
For example: tuesday 8h

i have tried to loop over the dates an put them in an array per day and go from there but it looks like a mess.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

The array looks like this

[image]

Comment: Mind showing the structure of the array?

Comment: Its just a flat array of carbon objects